# leaflet how to add circle by coordinates?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Next code is add circle to map:

```
var mylayer = L.circle([60, 54.75621], 200).addTo(Window.map);
```

but I want to add coordinates from variable: `eq.coordinates`

```
console.log(eq.coordinates);
```

Print on console: `POINT(31.5 42.2)`

I want to do something like:

```
var mylayer = L.circle(eq.coordinates).addTo(Window.map);
```

Answer (score 1):

L.circle wants latlng coordinates.

If you want to use pixel coordinates you have to convert them to latlng coordinates using http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-containerpointtolayerpoint

If you could put an example online, this would help helping you